# QT debugger's expression evaluation can not evaluate function result?

Tags: qt

When I use QT debugger, I set a break point on `each.first->currentIndex()`:
[image]

I want to know the evaluation value of `each.first->count()`, but I use `Add Expression Evaluator`, it just add another `each` into evaluator list, I still can't see the value. Isn't there any `Expression Evaluation` function in QT's debugger?

Answer (score 0):

What is the optimization level of your build? Even when building in debug mode some things can get optimized. You can use `CONFIG` in your project file to make sure you are using no optimization at all.

If this still doesn't work you can always create a temporary variable within this limited scope and check its value (should work). It will be optimized away anyway once you do a release build.

Comment: I'm in debug build, so nothing should be optimized out.
So it seems that I could only insert a local variable to hold the expression's value for debugger.